# Laravel schedule job with method when()

Tags: php, laravel

Where is error in below code?
I got Fatal error when I give `php artisan schedule:run` command in the terminal.

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->call(function () {
        $forgotCheckout = Working::whereNull('deleted_at')->get();
        $forgot = [];
            foreach($forgotCheckout as $forgot){
                $forgot;
            }
            Mail::send(
                'emails.forgot_checkout',
                compact('forgot'),
                function ($message) use ($forgot) {
                    $message->to('test@email.com');
                    $message->subject('This is test mail');

                }
            );
    })->daily()->when(function ($forgot){
        if(is_null($forgot)){
            return false;
        }
        else{
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError  : Type error: Too few arguments to function App\Console\Kernel::App\Console{closure}(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected

```
  at C:\www\test\app\Console\Kernel.php:50
    46|                         $message->subject('This is test mail');
    47|
    48|                     }
    49|                 );
  > 50|         })->everyMinute()->when(function ($forgot){
    51|             if(is_null($forgot)){
    52|                 return false;
    53|             }
    54|             else{
```

Comment: what is your intention with `$forgot` in the first place as you do nothing with it but reassign it inside an anonymous function via the foreach loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code.

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $forgot = [];
    $schedule->call(function () {
        $forgotCheckout = Working::whereNull('deleted_at')->get();

            foreach($forgotCheckout as $forgot){
                $forgot;
            }
            Mail::send(
                'emails.forgot_checkout',
                compact('forgot'),
                function ($message) use ($forgot) {
                    $message->to('test@email.com');
                    $message->subject('This is test mail');

                }
            );
    })->daily()->when(function() use($forgot) {
        if(is_null($forgot)){
            return false;
        }
        else{
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Changed line of code:

```
->daily()->when(function() use($forgot) {
```

Comment: `$forgot` has never been defined outside the scope of the previous anonymous function

Comment: @lagbox: you answer is correct, i got Undefined variable error in `})->daily()->when(function() use($forgot) {`, how could I solve that?

Comment: @Magnetic try to define the variable in the start of the method.

Comment: @JamalAbdulNasir: I edited with your answer, but I got this `No scheduled commands are ready to run.` How to solve it?

Comment: @JamalAbdulNasir. Didn't!! -_-;;

Comment: that would be better if you create a separate command class and register it in the kernel file.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at the [`Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Event` class source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Console/Scheduling/Event.php#L585), the method `when` runs the `Callable` object without passing any argument.

Instead your code requires an argument:

```
})->everyMinute()->when(function ($forgot){
```

So you have to change your code in order to use the `$forgot` variable (initializing it in your method) and change your code like this:

```
})->everyMinute()->when(function () use($forgot){
```